# how to solve tuple object has no attribute 'split error

Tags: python, tuples

I am trying to split the tuple data using below code  but getting an error "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'".

```py
request_number = ('1234567.t0',)

id = request_number.split(".")

print(id)

for i in range (len(id)):
    print (id[0])
```

Note: when I take input as a string it's working fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tuples have no split method, use a string, not a tuple. If the string is in a tuple, you can get it with slice e.g.

```
my_tuple[0].split('.')
```

In the case of the example, remove the brackets to get a string e.g.

```
request_number = '1234567.t0'
```

- [Tuple docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)
- [String method docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)

Comment: I guess you made a typo. **Tuples** have no split method.